# Java Annotation not recognized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-tool-suite

I have a spring boot application using @PreAuthorize for security checks. The validation works in my application if I start it by executing the gradle task bootRun. If I start the application from the Spring Tool Suite (using standard run configuration), the security checks do not work.

I think the problem is that the PreAuthorize annotation is not recognized when starting from STS. I can reproduce it with a simple gradle spring boot application using the same inheritance hierarchy as my real application.

- "DemoEntity" extends "BaseDemo" which extends "AbstractBaseEntity".
- "DemoService" extends "AbstractService" which implements "IEntityService"
- "DemoService" implements "IDemoService" which extends "IEntityService".

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class DemoEntity extends BaseDemo {}
public class BaseDemo extends AbstractBaseEntity {}
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {}

public class DemoService extends AbstractService<BaseDemo, DemoEntity> implements IDemoService {
    @Override
    @DemoAnnotation
    public void create(DemoEntity entity) {}
}

public interface IDemoService extends IEntityService<DemoEntity> {}

abstract class AbstractService<B extends AbstractBaseEntity, E extends B> implements IEntityService<E> {
    @Override
    public void create(E entity) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public interface IEntityService<E> {
    void create(E entity);
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DemoAnnotation {}
```

Note:

- I annotated the "create" method on the class DemoService.
- This method overrides the "create" method of AbstractService and it implements the method which is declared on IEntityService.

I print the methods and their annotations with the following code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AnnotationDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AnnotationDemoApplication.class, args);

        for (final Method method : DemoService.class.getMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().contains("create")) {
                System.out.println("Method: " + method.toString());
                final Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
                System.out.println("  #Annotations: " + annotations.length);
                for (final Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                    System.out.println("  Annotation: " + annotation.toString());
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When starting with the gradle task bootRun, I get the following result:

```
Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.DemoService.create(java.lang.Object)
  #Annotations: 1
  Annotation: @com.example.annotationdemo.DemoAnnotation()

Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.DemoService.create(com.example.annotationdemo.AbstractBaseEntity)
  #Annotations: 1
  Annotation: @com.example.annotationdemo.DemoAnnotation()

Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.DemoService.create(com.example.annotationdemo.DemoEntity)
  #Annotations: 1
  Annotation: @com.example.annotationdemo.DemoAnnotation()
```

The annotation is there for every method in the inheritance hierarchy.
When starting the application from STS, the result is:

```
Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.DemoService.create(com.example.annotationdemo.DemoEntity)
  #Annotations: 1
  Annotation: @com.example.annotationdemo.DemoAnnotation()

Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.DemoService.create(com.example.annotationdemo.AbstractBaseEntity)
  #Annotations: 0

Method: public void com.example.annotationdemo.AbstractService.create(java.lang.Object)
  #Annotations: 0
```

I think this demo reproduces the reason for my problem in the real application.
I created the project with spring initializr using Spring Boot 2.2.0, Java 11 and having no other dependency.

Can anybody tell me, why STS produces other results than running bootRun?
Do I need to add a parameter or setting in my STS so that it behaves the same way as bootRun?

Comment: Annotations aren't inherited in the tree. So I would actually expect the result from STS to be the actual result, whereas the other one (bootRun) is the wrong one. Only the method `create(DemoEntity)` is annotated, not the other ones. Make sure you are using the same JDK and same version.

Comment: I agree. But it also means that I've not yet found my real application's problem. In my real application, the annotation checks the security and when starting from STS, the security check is ignored. The method is called through a autowired IDemoService (where I actually have a DemoService object). If I change the code to directly autowire the DemoService (not its interface), then the security check works.